# How to set a timer but don't run repeatly

Tags: java

In my case I created a object and planned to release it after 20 minutes(accuracy is not necessary). I know by using `java.util.Timer` I can create a timer.But I just want it run once. After that,the timer should stop and been released too.

Is there any way just like `setTimeOut()` in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture = 10000; // 10 sec
Date timeToRun = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture);
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Task here ...
        }
    }, timeToRun);
```

Modify above so that you can schedule a job 20 minutes in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Timer::schedule(TimerTask, long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29)  or look into the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new thread and call `sleep` with the number of milliseconds to wait, then execute your instructions (on either thread). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html for reference, and look at the various online thread tutorials if you need more help.

Comment: This is almost the worst way posible to execute a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Timer` has a cancel method in it:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29

However, as far as I know, in timer if you do not specify a period, scheduled task will run only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stevej;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StackOverflowMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    Runnable myAction = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello (2 minutes into the future)");
      }
    };

    executor.schedule(myAction, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }
}
```